# Says I am seg faulting when i place an item in the beginning of the array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault

Edit: Ok, so for some reason I thought the scanf line would read in the entire line as a string (multiple arguments). Brain must really be fried. Thank you all for your help.

I am trying to place some chars into an array. Here is how the code looks.

Edit: adding more code to hopefully shed more light in the problem
Edit2: can I treat the char pointer "message" like a string in this function?

```
//in main...
printf( "Enter a command> " );
scanf( "%s", buf );
message = convertMessage( buf );
//....

char* convertMessage( char *message ){
    char *convMess = calloc( 50, sizeof(char) );
    char *tok = strtok( message, " ," );

    if( convMess == NULL ){
        perror( "memory error" );
        exit(-5);
    }

    if( strcmp( tok, "get" ) == 0 ){
        tok = strtok( NULL, " ," );
        if( strcmp( tok, "lname" ) == 0 ){
            convMess[0] = '1';   // seg faults on this line
            convMess[1] = ' ';
            strcat( convMess, tok );
            return convMess;
        }
        else if( //...        
            //...and so on
//output from gdb
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400e5d in convertMessage (
message=0x7fffffffbfa0 "get") at client.c:135
135             if( strcmp( tok, "lname" ) == 0 ){
(gdb) quit
```

I know I am probably misunderstanding something very simple but I have been working on this code for so long I think my mind has fried. Also, I have checked the online references and the code on cplusplus.com/reference looks the same as what I have.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your code is fine. Maybe you should check conMess is not NULL... but I don't think the problem is there.

Comment: Also need to check that `tok` is not NULL before calling `strcmp` (x2).

Comment: Are you sure the second call to `strtok()` isn't returning `NULL` and that the crash isn't really happening in the second `strcmp()` call?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I tried to print the value of tok right after the second tokenizing in the if statement and the seg fault prevented the printing.

Comment: @user1362058: so to clarify: trying to print out `tok` caused a segfault?

Comment: @user1362058 How are you calling this function ? Maybe you pass some garbage in. Or maybe you pass a string literal, e.g. convertMessage("some string"); which is not going to work since you can't change a string literal.

Comment: this is what gdb outputs. Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400e5d in convertMessage (
    message=0x7fffffffbfa0 "get") at client.c:135
135             if( strcmp( tok, "lname" ) == 0 ){
(gdb) quit

Comment: @MaximSkurydin I don't know if it matters or not but this code is running on a linux server somewhere. I don't know if that would mess with address allocation or anything like that.

Comment: It looks like `tok` is `NULL`. Look at or print out what the `message` string is before the first call to `strtok()` - I'll bet there are no tokens after "get".

Comment: @MichaelBurr you are right. I was misusing the scanf function. I wanted to read the entire line from the user not just the first word.

Answer (score 3):

You might be compiling for a 64-bit platform without including `stdlib.h` - if there's no declaration/prototype for `calloc()` the compiler will truncate the returned pointer to an `int` (assuming an `int` is 32 bits).

Use appropriate compiler options to have the compiler generate a warning or error for this kind of thing.

Comment: I am compiling with 3 flags, Wall, ansi, and pedantic. I also have the stdlib.h as an include file.

Answer (score 2):

From you posting I see the app segfaults in line135:

```
if( strcmp( tok, "lname" ) == 0 ){
```

Most propably you are passing in `tok`, with `tok` being `NULL`.

You might want to check the value of `tok` against `NULL` after having it assigned in line 134:

```
tok = strtok( NULL, " ," );
```

before passing it to `strcmp()`, like so for example:

```
 tok = strtok( NULL, " ," );
 if (tok != NULL) {
   if (strcmp( tok, "lname" ) == 0 ) {
   ...
 }
```